# Stray start tag HTML in validator?

Tags: html, validation

I am trying to validate this HTML document in http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input but I am getting the following errors:

Line 3, Column 47: Stray start tag html.

```
<!--[if IE 7]><!--><html lang="en" class="ie7"><!--<![endif]-->
```

Line 4, Column 47: Stray start tag html.

```
<!--[if IE 8]><!--><html lang="en" class="ie8"><!--<![endif]-->
```

Line 5, Column 47: Stray start tag html.

```
<!--[if IE 9]><!--><html lang="en" class="ie9"><!--<![endif]-->
```

Line 6, Column 46: Stray start tag html.

```
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->
```

This is the HTML I am inputting:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<!--[if IE 7]><!--><html lang="en" class="ie7"><!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><!--><html lang="en" class="ie8"><!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]><!--><html lang="en" class="ie9"><!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Correct conditional comments:

```
<!--[if IE 7]><html lang="en" class="ie7"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html lang="en" class="ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]><html lang="en" class="ie9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><html lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><html lang="en-US"><![endif]-->
```

Comment: Yes. To clarify, the `<html>` tags are not really conditional in the OP's code. To a non-IE user agent, they're all visible.

Comment: Thank you. Of course - I feel silly now. It now works perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

You don't close them. That's all and you define 2 html tags now.

Answer (score 1):

You start with a html-tag that's always present and then you add html-tags depending on version of IE so you might very well end up with multiple html-tags.

Comment: Thank you! Ozerich's solution and your explanation helped me to understand where I was going wrong. Many thanks.

Answer (score -2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Use this file and then start  tag...