# Stray start tag html

Tags: html

My w3c validator check bought up the following error.

Line 9, Column 53: Stray start tag html.

```
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Here is the full code.

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" dir="<?php echo $this->direction; ?>" >

 <!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
 <!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
 <!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
 <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Where is the stray start tag?. What would be the correct version of this code?

Thanks

Paul

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16123945/stray-start-tag-html-in-validator

Comment: I did look at that article, but when I implemented the code. It messed up my website. I just want to know where is the stray start tag and what the correct code would be? Thanks

Comment: Here is the whole code. Maybe the stray start tag will be easier to identify.